# Remove specific letter in a string in R

Tags: r

I have strings like this:
*the string is in class "factor"

```
string1= "applepearbananao234range"
string2= "appleorangewater342melon"
string3= "applepearwaterme436lonkl"
s_df=rbind(string1,string2,string3)
s_df=data.frame(s_df)
```

I would like to remove the word apple (which is the first 5 letters) and the numbers at position 16 to 18 in the data frame s_df .

Edit: the codes and the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub`

```
gsub("apple|23", "", string1)
#[1] "pearbananaorange"
```

Or with `str_remove_all`

```
stringr::str_remove_all(string1, "apple|23")
```

For the updated data, we can do

```
gsub("^apple|\\d+", "", s_df$s_df)
#[1] "pearbananaorange" "orangewatermelon" "pearwatermelonkl"
```

Comment: Hi, i edit the code and questions a little bit, cuz i did some alternation to the data. thanks!

Comment: @GarlicSTAT Do you have any other numbers in the data? I updated the code with `gsub("^apple|\\d+", "", s_df$s_df)`, can you check if it helps ?

Comment: It works perfectly fine! But is there a way that I can remove the "letter/digit" at position 16-18?

Comment: @GarlicSTAT Maybe you can use `substring` in two parts and then combine. `paste0(substring(s_df$s_df, 1, 15), substring(s_df$s_df, 19, 24))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(string1, "apple|23", "")
#[1] "pearbananao4range"
```